# Axios data not being carried over to data when mounted in Vue

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, twitch, twitch-api

I'm trying to call data from the Twitch [IGDB](https://api-docs.igdb.com/?javascript#account-creation) API (with this we use POST instead of GET) with axios calls in Vue 2, but it's not working like I expect it to. I can log the `access_token`, but not the data from the fetch request.

I've made a separate file with the API requests which I'm imported in a Vue component, which looks like this:

```js
import axios from "axios";

// Variables for Twitch Authorization
const client_id = process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID;
const client_secret = process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET;
const grant_type = "client_credentials";
const cors_server = "process.env.VUE_APP_CORS_ANYWHERE_SERVER";

// Get access token from Twitch Dev Account
export async function getAccessToken() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}&grant_type=${grant_type}`
    );
    const data = await response.data.access_token;

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
  }
};

// Call Games from API
export function getGames(accessToken) {
  axios({
    url: `${cors_server}https://api.igdb.com/v4/games`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/JSON',
        'Client-ID': client_id,
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    data: "fields *;",
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
    return res.data;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
};
```

I've imported this into the component like this:

```js
import { getAccessToken, getGames } from "./api_requests";
```

I've defined the data like this:

```js
data() {
    return {
      games: null,
      accessToken: '',
    }
  },
```

And am calling the data in `mounted` like this.

```js
  // Calling data from IGDB
  async mounted() {
    this.accessToken = await getAccessToken();
    getGames(this.accessToken).then(res => {
      this.games = res;
      console.log(this.games);
    });
```

I've tried different ways to call `getGames` in `mounted` but I just can't get it to save in the `data` correctly. Should I be calling this a different way? Is importing it causing problems? Should I make a method inside the component instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. `getGames()` needs to return `axios()` so that the caller can receive the value of the response data:

```js
export function getGames(accessToken) {
  return axios({/*...*/})
}
```

Then the caller could just `await` it:

```js
async mounted() {
  this.games = await getGames(this.accessToken)
}
```